# MySQL stored procedure - Select if parameter is given else exclude it

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I have a mysql stored procedure, i need to exclude a parameter if its value is not given.
if i call the stored procedure with two parameter it should able to run excluding the program condition.

**MY CURRENT QUERY**

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE GetUtilization2(
    IN programName VARCHAR(30),
    IN date1 VARCHAR(20),
    IN date2 VARCHAR(20)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
SUM(task_hours) as total,
(SUM(CASE when task_category = 'Production' THEN task_hours ELSE 0 END)/SUM(task_hours)) * 100 AS production,
(SUM(CASE when task_category = 'Non Production' THEN task_hours ELSE 0 END)/SUM(task_hours)) * 100  AS non_production,
(SUM(CASE when task_category = 'Training' THEN task_hours ELSE 0 END)/SUM(task_hours)) * 100  AS Training,
(SUM(CASE when task_category = 'Absenteeism' THEN task_hours ELSE 0 END)/SUM(task_hours)) * 100  AS Absenteeism,
(SUM(CASE when utilization_type = 'Extended' THEN task_hours ELSE 0 END) /((SUM(task_hours)-SUM(CASE when utilization_type = 'Extended' THEN task_hours ELSE 0 END)))) * 100 AS OT
    FROM data_table
    WHERE program = programName and date(task_date)  between date1 and date2;
    
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
**If Program not given exclude program from query** 

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE GetUtilization2(
    IN programName VARCHAR(30),
    IN date1 VARCHAR(20),
    IN date2 VARCHAR(20)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
SUM(task_hours) as total,
(SUM(CASE when task_category = 'Production' THEN task_hours ELSE 0 END)/SUM(task_hours)) * 100 AS production,
(SUM(CASE when task_category = 'Non Production' THEN task_hours ELSE 0 END)/SUM(task_hours)) * 100  AS non_production,
(SUM(CASE when task_category = 'Training' THEN task_hours ELSE 0 END)/SUM(task_hours)) * 100  AS Training,
(SUM(CASE when task_category = 'Absenteeism' THEN task_hours ELSE 0 END)/SUM(task_hours)) * 100  AS Absenteeism,
(SUM(CASE when utilization_type = 'Extended' THEN task_hours ELSE 0 END) /((SUM(task_hours)-SUM(CASE when utilization_type = 'Extended' THEN task_hours ELSE 0 END)))) * 100 AS OT
    FROM data_table
    WHERE date(task_date)  between date1 and date2;
    
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

OPTIONAL : Can u make the query in more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE (programName is null or program = programName)
  AND date(task_date) between date1 and date2;
```

And don't use `varchar` as data type for your date. Use  `date` or  `datetime`. Your query will probably run faster if you don't use functions that prevent using indexes:

Instead of

```
date(task_date) between date1 and date2
```

use

```
task_date >= date1 and task_date < (date2 + interval 1 day)
```